# why code is 'src' in aspx page after html code generation again is 'original'?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image

In aspx page code as follow:

```
<div id="translate_popup" style="display:none;">
        <table class="translate_links"><tbody><tr>
        <td valign="top">            
            <a title="English" href="#"  rel="en" class="languagelink"><img height="11" width="16" alt="English" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/transparent.gif") %>" class="translate_flag en"> English</a>
            <a title="Arabic" href="#" rel="ar" class="languagelink"><img height="11" width="16" alt="العربية" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/transparent.gif") %>" class="translate_flag ar"> العربية</a>
            <a title="Bulgarian" href="#" rel="bg" class="languagelink"><img height="11" width="16" alt="български" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/transparent.gif") %>" class="translate_flag bg"> български</a>
            <a title="Catalan" href="#" rel="ca" class="languagelink"><img height="11" width="16" alt="català" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/transparent.gif") %>" class="translate_flag ca"> català</a>

... 
</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

After code generation is 'original' in html page

```
    <div style="left: 301px; top: 2854px; display: block;" id="translate_popup">
            <table class="translate_links"><tbody><tr>
            <td valign="top">

                <a class="languagelink" rel="en" href="#" title="English"><img height="11" width="16" class="translate_flag en" alt="English" original="/6147/Content/Images/transparent.gif" style=""> English</a>
                <a class="languagelink" rel="ar" href="#" title="Arabic"><img height="11" width="16" class="translate_flag ar" alt="العربية" original="/6147/Content/Images/transparent.gif" style=""> العربية</a>
                <a class="languagelink" rel="bg" href="#" title="Bulgarian"><img height="11" width="16" class="translate_flag bg" alt="български" original="/6147/Content/Images/transparent.gif" style=""> български</a>
                <a class="languagelink" rel="ca" href="#" title="Catalan"><img height="11" width="16" class="translate_flag ca" alt="català" original="/6147/Content/Images/transparent.gif" style=""> català</a>

...             
</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

I use jquery.translate.js i don't know this can be the cause of the error or not.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That should be: `rel="alternate" hreflang="the language"` not `rel="the language"`

Comment: Actually, since the content of the link is also in that language you should have a `lang` attribute too.

Comment: I've no idea what your question is though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put **/** at end of each img tag...

```
<img .... />
```